# Point to Point Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation

http://postimg.org/image/8bwxdp4bj/7124c28f/
    I want to make animation shown in above image .I am using this code .they became move to infinity and my view will not appear because they involved in for loop. I am newer in iOS . Please help.what i do I am stuck.Any help would be appreciated.

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if (i==0) {
           first.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
           second.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            third.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            button.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            i=1;
        }
        if (i==1) {
            first.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            second.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            third.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            button.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            i=2;
       }
        if (i==2) {
            first.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            second.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            third.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            button.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            i=3;
        }
       if (i==3) {
            first.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            second.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
           third.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            button.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            i=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: why not using [UIPageControl](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/changing-screens-with-uipagecontrol)? & if you are looking for customize then look [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/styledpagecontrol) & [here too](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uipagecontrol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly make a **global** variable which keeps track of which button's background is changed and also an array which stores all the buttons.

```
@interface ClassName() {
    int index = 0;
    NSArray *buttons;
}
```

Now in the initialization method, do this

```
[first setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[second setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[third setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
buttons = @[first, second, third, button];
[self performSelector:@selector(changeColor) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
```

Now in your `changeColor` method, do like this

```
- (void)changeColor {

    UIButton *btn = [buttons objectAtIndex:index];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    UIButton *prevBtn = [buttons objectAtIndex:((index - 1) + 4) % 4];
    [prevBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    index = ++ index % 4;
    [self performSelector:@selector(changeColor) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: thnks buddy you are my saviour

Comment: This answer was according to question posted by the user. Unfortunately the user have removed the question. The user doesn't need a UIPageControl.